# Smartface android actionbar menu icon change

Tags: smartface.io

I want to change menu icon to the left of the title. My codes as follows. But I guess I writing wrong code. How Can I do this?

```js
        var leftitemm = new SMF.UI.Android.MenuItem({
        
            id: "itemBack",
            icon: "ico_submenu_back.png",
            showAsAction: SMF.UI.Android.ShowAsAction.always,
            onSelected: function(e) {
                alert("Back item selected");
            }
        
        })
        
       header.setLeftItem(leftitemm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change left menu item by adding that line :" this.actionBar.homeAsUpIndicator  = 'icon.png';" in HeaderBar.js.

```
    this.setLeftItem = function () {

        if (this.isAndroid == true) {
            this.actionBar.displayHomeAsUpEnabled = true;
            this.actionBar.displayShowHomeEnabled = true;
            this.actionBar.homeAsUpIndicator  = "icon.png";
            this.actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function () {
                alert("Home Button clicked");
            }
        } else{
            ...
          }
    }
```